# url redirection in magento not working with index.php

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I want to redirect url in magento. I am using "URL rewrite Management".

We want this path "/index.php?cPath=1" redirect to  "baby-prams-strollers.html" this path.

I have entering data this type

```
Request Path *   index.php?cPath=1
Target Path      baby-prams-strollers.html
```

But it will be redirect on homepage. we want to redirect on baby-prams-strollers.html this path. How can we do this? Please advice me.

If we have entered this type of data

```
Request Path *   ?cPath=1
Target Path      baby-prams-strollers.html
```

Now it will be redirected on "baby-prams-strollers.html" this path but url is coming with index.php/baby-prams-strollers.html. Now we don't need index.php in URL. How can we remove index.php in this URL. We have already removed index.php in our all url. but when we redirection of this type url that time it will be added url in index.php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your .htaccess file in your Magento root folder soomething like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php?cPath=1(.*) /baby-prams-strollers.html$1
```